# Android Studio - File Explorer doesnt show all my folders

Tags: android, file, system, emulation

I am using Android Studio to emulate a basic android 4.3 device. Using the Android Device Monitor - file explorer function I am looking through the emulated file system and not all of the folders which I know exist are being shown. For instance under an installed application (on my rooted test device using a file explorer, I know folders exist in a particular location), but when I check on the emulation, I cnt see these folders.

Does the emulator not offer complete access to the file system?

another example is that the downloads folder has an image in it, but on the emulator, the file path shows the downloads folder to be empty - or it wont show me the content.

Is there away round this?

Thanks